# react-native-gesture-handler module error

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

ERROR  [react-native-gesture-handler] react-native-gesture-handler module was not found. Make sure you're running your app on the native platform and your code is linked properly (cd ios && pod install && cd ..)
Trying to run it on android.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this issue by adding this:

```
npm install react-native-gesture-handler

npx react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
```

Comment: bonus if your new to react-native-gesture-handler, don't forget to add <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}> at the app level.

Comment: $ npx react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
error: unknown command 'link'